# How do I embed jqPlot in Grails? Are there any special tags?

Tags: javascript, html, grails, statistics, jqplot

I'm working on a web application, and I'm supposed to use the Grails framework (I've just started learning Grails about a week ago). I know how to create websites and jqPlot graphics using HTML, Javascript and the like. However, I can't seem to find any information on how I could implement jqPlot in a Grails view. I wonder if there are any special tags like `<g:...` (the Grails html tag) or perhaps even something like `<jqplot:...` - on the Grails plugin page `<jqplot:resources/>` and `<jqplot:plugin name="pieRenderer"/>` are given, but somehow that list feels incomplete. Isn't there a Grails way to avoid writing $.jqplot(...) in javascript?

Also, I'd love to see actual "jqPlot in Grails" examples, are there any resources of that kind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using any plugin, you can add the jqPlot into your application, meaning copy the project files into your `web-app` directory.  Assuming you are working with Grails 2.x, in your `applicationResources.groovy` in your conf directory where you define your resources modules define the jqPlot resources. Add the files you need into this module so you can use them inside your application.  You need to read the jqPlot documentation to make sure you are including all the required resources related to your graph.

```
    visualization {
        dependsOn 'jquery'
        resource url: 'jquery.jqplot/excanvas.min.js'   ,disposition:'head' , bundle:'app'
        resource url: 'jquery.jqplot/jquery.jqplot.min.js'  ,disposition:'head' , bundle:'app'
        resource url: 'jquery.jqplot/jquery.jqplot.min.css' ,disposition:'head' , bundle:'app'

        resource url: 'jquery.jqplot/plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js' ,disposition:'head'    , bundle:'app'
        resource url: 'jquery.jqplot/plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.min.js'  ,disposition:'head' , bundle:'app'
        resource url: 'jquery.jqplot/plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisLabelRenderer.min.js' ,disposition:'head' , bundle:'app'
        resource url: 'jquery.jqplot/plugins/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.min.js'  ,disposition:'head' , bundle:'app'
        resource url: 'jquery.jqplot/plugins/jqplot.cursor.min.js'  ,disposition:'head' , bundle:'app'
        resource url: 'jquery.jqplot/plugins/jqplot.bubbleRenderer.min.js'  ,disposition:'head' , bundle:'app'
        resource url: 'jquery.jqplot/plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js'    ,disposition:'head' , bundle:'app'
    }
```

On the page you want to use jqplog just include visualization modile.

```
<r:require modules="visualization"/>
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. And is there also a grails tag that I could use instead of the $.jqplot() function? I guess that is what I was aiming at.

Comment: There is a `":jqplot:0.1"` plugin but seems to be in a very early stage and never get updated since 2010. Take a look at it see if you can use it. imo Libraries like this would be easier to use them directly and the same way you do it on html pages. There are a lot of options you might need to set that becomes just easier to have it as javascript.

Comment: So I tried your example. Where exactly do I have to unpack the jquery and jqplot libraries to make it work?

Comment: Those will go to web-app directory, in my example, I have them all in `jquery.jqplot` folder.